# Angular directive with onkeypress not being called on Android phone

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 4 / Angular 7 application where I have the following custom directive:

```
    @Directive({
      selector: '[appNumeric]'
    })

    export class NumericDirective {
      //HostListener decorator handle event handlers for input (onKeyPress)
      @HostListener('keypress', ['$event'])

      public onkeypress(ev : any): void {  
        let isNumeric = ev.charCode >= 48 && ev.keyCode <= 57;
        if (!isNumeric)
          ev.preventDefault();      
      }
    }
```

And I apply this as follows

```
<ion-input appNumeric>
```

When I test running on Chrome on my PC (eg Ionic serve), it works fine, but when I run on the Android phone, it does not fire at all.

Why would this be so?

Comment: keypress doesn't work on mobile devices. Use `ionInput` to listen for input changes. Also, seems you just want to allow only numbers, right? So why not just `<ion-input type="number">` ?

Comment: Thankyou @JuliusDzidzevičius. I am sure I tried the `type="number"` before I did the directive and found it not to work. Yet, I tried it again, and it does exactly what I am after (so no need for the directive at all). If add as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer

Comment: Ok, great. Added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keypress` doesn't work on mobile devices. Use `ionInput` to listen for input changes. Also, seems you just want to allow only numbers, right? So why not just `<ion-input type="number">`